# Binding Interfaces With Fastify and Fastify-HTTP-Proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, fastify

I'm using `fastify` and `fastify-http-proxy` on a VPS (Ubuntu 19.x) that has three IPv4 addresses. I can verify their functionality with (example IPs):

```
curl --interface 45.63.23.63 api.ipify.org
curl --interface 45.63.72.48 api.ipify.org
curl --interface 45.63.40.39 api.ipify.org
```

I see [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_url_options_callback) that you can supply an interface by supplying a `localAddress` to Node's `http` requests. Has anyone done this with `fastify` or `fastify-http-proxy`? I've searched both and can't find support in each package for it.

I run an API which forwards traffic to a host. Recently, it received a lot of (legitimate) traffic and the host's (Sony) DDoS prevention flagged and blocked it due to high traffic from a single address. When contacted, they claimed to not be able to remove the block, but that I was free to change my VPS' IP. To prevent this in the future, I'd like to almost randomize which interface it uses.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by setting:

```js
server.register(require('fastify-http-proxy'), {
  upstream: 'http://my-api.example.com',
  prefix: '/api',
  http: {
    requestOptions: {
      localAddress: '45.63.72.48'
    }
  }
})
```

In this way, all your requests will have that IP. All the request options are supported using [this settings](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-reply-from/tree/2.x#http), since `fastify-reply-from` is used under the hood.

But you have 3 ips to use, so you need to register three times the plugin per different routes, or build a "round getter" like this should work as well:

```js
const ips = [
  '45.63.23.63',
  '45.63.72.48',
  '45.63.40.39'
]
let endlessIterator = ips[Symbol.iterator]()

const roundIps = {
  get localAddress () {
    let v = endlessIterator.next().value
    if (!v) {
      endlessIterator = ips[Symbol.iterator]()
      v = endlessIterator.next().value
    }
    return v
  }
}

server.register(require('fastify-http-proxy'), {
  upstream: 'http://my-api.example.com',
  prefix: '/api',
  http: {
    requestOptions: roundIps
  }
})
```

Comment: Excellent reply. Very informative and great idea! Thank you!

Comment: Just wanted to add - I've had time to try your approach and it works fantastic. The getter was brilliant and I hadn't thought of it!